# Add character to empty html tags with c# and regex

Tags: c#, html, regex

I want to find all empty HTML tags in a string, eg:

```
<div></div>
<span>test</span>
<a></a>
```

and add a space or a character to all of the empty tags in that string:

```
<div>something</div>
<span>test</span>
<a>something</a>
```

I've got an regex that matches all empty tags, but I'm not sure what's the best way replace the tags.

Regex:

```
<(\w+)(?:\s+\w+="[^"]+(?:"\$[^"]+"[^"]+)?")*>\s*</\1>
```

Comment: Tip: use HtmlAgilityPack (regex is overkill)

Comment: [regex is not overkill. it is "underkill"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1733489) :) Use a HTML/XML parser and interate over the DOM tree - this'll save you a lot of pain.

Comment: From what I've read the agilitypack can mess up the rest of the html making "fixes" to certain tags like <img />..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

Handling this via regex is probably not the best way to go, however because there may be reasons for using a regular expression such as "I'm not allowed to install HTMLAgilityPack" then this expression will:

- find all tags which are simply open tag followed by a close tag
- will avoid many of the edge cases that make pattern matching in HTML with regex difficult

Regex: `(<(\w+)(?=\s|>)(?:[^'">=]*|='[^']*'|="[^"]*"|=[^'"][^\s>]*)*>)(<\/\2>)`

Replace with: `$1~~~NewValue~~~$3`

[image]

## Example

[Live Demo](http://regexr.com?35nqh)

**Sample Text**

Note the first line has some really difficult edge cases

```
<a onmouseover=' str=" <a></a> " ; if ( 6 > 4 ) { funDoSomething(str); } '></a>
<div></div>
<span>test</span>
<a></a>
```

**Text After Replacement**

```
<a onmouseover=' str=" <a></a> " ; if ( 6 > 4 ) { funDoSomething(str); } '>~~~NewValue~~~</a>
<div>~~~NewValue~~~</div>
<span>test</span>
<a>~~~NewValue~~~</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
foreach(HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//*").Where(x=>x.InnerText==""))
{
       node.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(HtmlTextNode.CreateNode(input), node);
}
doc.Save(yourFile);
```

Comment: What If I dont got a complete html document? I just have a small part of a larger document and I just want to replace some tags.. Still the way to go? I feel like the crowd just have decided that if HTML and Regex is mencioned in a question HTML parser is the only option...

Comment: @f01 No matter in what form your html is in..be it `incomplete`,`no end tags!`,`not an html!!!` this parser would still work perfectly without any issues..

Comment: @f01 you could use a regex like `(?<=<.*?[^/]>)(?=</.*?>)` and replace it with `something`.. **BUT** i can give you 1000 cases where you would break your application

Answer (score 0):

Use [Html Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for Html Parsing [never regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2610249).

Comment: -1 because your proposed solution doesn't really provide an answer to the question. At best this is some vague direction to a rather specific request.